# Find a difficult integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to find the following intergal:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\text{n}}{1+x^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

I've no idea where to start, I've tried integration by parts but it lead not to a closed form.

Comment: "I''ve no idea where to start!" is not a valid comment on this site.

Comment: @5xum I'm sorry, I tried IBP but it does not work.

Comment: WA says $$\frac{1}{2}\pi\sec\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I know that, but that is not a proof.

Comment: Am I missing something or does it diverge for $n\ge 1$ and for $n=0$ it's $arctan$?

Comment: @RabMakh The integral converges when: $$-1<\Re\left(\text{n}\right)<1$$

Comment: So actually $n \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco In my problem I know that $\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$. But in the general case, it is possible to have a complex number in $\text{n}$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Your expression are conditioned to the value of $n$!

Comment: What about a trick that reduces it (via reduction formula) to $$I_n=\frac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}-I_{n-2}$$?

Comment: @Kevin I'm looking for a closed form.

Comment: @Kevin What is $x$ in the formula?

Comment: Isn't that just a special case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530926/finding-a-difficult-integral?rq=1)?

Comment: I found **a lot** of duplicate questions using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bx%5En%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7Ddx%24%2C%20%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5En%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7Ddx%24&p=1)

Comment: About the link provided by @ProfessorVector . You have done a more general integral there, how is this one difficult? You trying to find an alternative way of doing this or what? Because this is really strange...

Comment: @5xum I have evaluated the indefinite form, granted with those limits in the OP my hint may not help (at all).

Comment: See https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/prove-following-reduction-formula-integrate-tan-n-364529

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have full answer, but I may give an idea by **finding pattern** and then using **Induction**.

- First, if $n=1$, we have
  $$ \int \frac{x}{1+x^{2}}dx = \int \frac{1}{2} \frac{d(1+x^{2})}{dx} dx = \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+x^{2})  $$
- Second, if $n=2$, we have
  $$  \int \frac{x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}dx = \int 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} dx = x - \tan^{-1}(x) $$
- Third, if $n=3$, we have
  $$  \int \frac{x^{3}}{1+x^{2}}dx =  x(x-\tan^{-1}(x)) - \int(x-\tan^{-1}(x))dx  $$
  Note that $\int \tan^{-1}(x)dx = x \tan^{-1}(x) - \frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{2} $ ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_inverse_trigonometric_functions))
  so we have 
  $$ \int \frac{x^{3}}{1+x^{2}}dx = \frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{\ln(1+x^{2})}{2}  $$
- Fourth, if $n=4$, we have
  $$ \int \frac{x^{4}}{1+x^{2}}dx = \int \frac{x^{4}-1+1}{1+x^{2}} dx $$
  $$ = \int (x^{2}-1) + \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} dx = \frac{x^{3}}{3} -x + \tan^{-1}(x)$$
- Continue until you found a pattern .....

  > You can see that when $n=1$ and $n=3$ we have only two types : *even
  >   degree power* plus $0.5 \ln(1+x^{2})$. While when $n=2$ and $n=4$, we
  >   have only two types : *odd degree power* plus $\tan^{-1}(x)$. You
  >   could found a pattern here, then use induction to prove it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The original integral doesn't even converge when $n>1$...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like so.
Note that:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \exp (-x t) \sin (t) \, dt=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

so,

$$\color{red}{\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{1+x^2} \, dx}=\\\int_0^{\infty } \left(\int_0^{\infty } x^n \exp (-x t) \sin (t) \, dx\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } t^{-1-n}
   \Gamma (1+n) \sin (t) \, dt=\\-\Gamma (-n) \Gamma (1+n) \sin \left(\frac{n \pi }{2}\right)=\\\color{red}{\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sec \left(\frac{n \pi }{2}\right)}$$

for: $\color{red}{-1<\Re(n)<1}$

Addition:
$-\Gamma (-n) \Gamma (1+n)=\pi  \csc (n \pi )$