# Evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^n} \,\mathrm{d}x $?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, cauchy-principal-value

The  cauchy principal value of
$
\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^n}\,\mathrm{d}x
$ is defined as :

$$
\begin{cases}
{\displaystyle A=0\,,\quad n\in \mathbb{N^*}}
\\[2mm]
{\displaystyle A=\frac{\pi\left(-1\right)^{m}}{\left(n - 1\right)!}\,,\qquad
n \in 2\mathbb{N}+1\,,\quad n = 2m + 1}
\end{cases}
$$.

**My question here is** : 
How we can prove that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{n}}\,\mathrm{d}x =A
$$ .

Comment: It's quite unclear how you're defining $m$ and $\mathbb{N}^*$. Care to clarify? Also, Wolfram Alpha seems to think that the integral is divergent for $n > 1$.

Comment: yes , it is divergent for n >1

Comment: Probably the function is $\displaystyle \frac{\sin^n (x)}{x^n}$?

Comment: The Cauchy principal value is usually only well-defined if a function has simple poles on the real axis.  This function has a pole of order $n-1$ on the real axis, which won't be a simple pole unless $n = 2$.

Comment: Actually, that's not accurate; the Cauchy principal value of $\int x^{-3} \, dx$ exists and is zero. However, the usual contour integration method fails in this case for $n \geq 3$, and I'm not sure why.  I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: No, never mind, I'm still confused about your definition.  If $n$ is odd and greater than or equal to three, then $\sin(z)/z^n$ will scale as $\mathcal{O}(z^{1-n})$ near $z = 0$.  The contributions from the boundaries at $\pm \epsilon$ when we integrate this will then be something like $[z^{2-n}]_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}$.  If $n$ is odd and greater than 2, this quantity will diverge as $\epsilon \to 0$, and the Cauchy Principal Value will not exist.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is incomplete;  it uses a standard method for evaluating the principal value of a contour integral, but fails for reasons I can't quite understand.  Any comments to fix it, or pointing out why it's fatally flawed, would be appreciated.

---

The simplest way is to use the [residue theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)  To apply this, consider the contour in the complex plane of the following form:

- I. From $z = +\epsilon$ to $z = R$, along the real axis
- II.From $z = R$ to $z = -R$, in a semi-circle centered at $z = 0$ in the upper half of the complex plane
- III. From $z = -R$ to $z = - \epsilon$, along the real axis
- IV. From $z = - \epsilon$ to $z = + \epsilon$, in a semi-circle centered at $z = 0$ in the upper half of the complex plane.

Consider the integral of the functions $f(z) = e^{iz}/z^n$ along this contour.  Note that $\sin z/z^n$ is the imaginary part of $f(z)$.

In the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$, the contributions from portions I and III of the contour become the Cauchy principal value of this integral.  Moreover, since $f(z)$ converges to 0 as $z \to \infty$ in any direction in the upper half-plane, the integral over portion $II$ of the contour will go to zero in this limit.  Finally, we note that this function does not contain any poles in the upper half-plane, so the integral around our contour will be zero.  Putting this all together, we conclude that
$$
\mathrm{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) \, dz + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{III} f(z) \, dz = 0.
$$
So to find the Cauchy principal value, we must perform the integral around the small semi-circle in a clockwise direction.  Along this curve, we have $z = \epsilon e^{i \phi}$, with $\phi$ running from $\pi$ to $0$.  Thus,
$$
\int_{III} f(z) \, dz = \int_{\pi}^0 f(\epsilon e^{i \phi}) \left( \epsilon i e^{i \phi} \right) \, d \phi.
$$
Now, if we expand $f(z)$ in a Laurent series about $z = 0$, we have
$$
f(z) = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{i^m z^{m-n}}{m!}
$$
and so
$$
f(\epsilon e^{i \phi}) \left( \epsilon i e^{i \phi} \right) = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{i^{m+1} \epsilon^{m-n+1}}{m!} e^{i \phi (m -n + 1)}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_{\pi}^0 f(\epsilon e^{i \phi}) \left( \epsilon i e^{i \phi} \right) \, d \phi = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \left[ \frac{i^{m+1} \epsilon^{m-n+1}}{m!} \int_\pi^0 e^{i \phi (m - n + 1)} d \phi \right].
$$
For $m - n + 1 \neq 0$, this integral becomes 
$$
\int_\pi^0 e^{i \phi (m - n + 1)} d \phi = \begin{cases}
2 /i(m - n + 1) & m - n \text{ even} \\
0 & m - n \text{ odd}
\end{cases} \\
$$
while for $m - n + 1 = 0$, the integral is simply $-\pi$.  Thus, we have
$$
\int_{III} f(z) \, dz = -\frac{\pi i^{n}}{(n-1)!}  + 2\sum_{m -n \text{ even}}^\infty \frac{i^{m} \epsilon^{m-n+1}}{m!(m-n+1)}
$$
If $n$ is even, then all the terms in this expression will be real, and so the imaginary part will vanish.  If $n$ is odd, then this expression will be purely imaginary, so we have
$$
\Im \int_{III} f(z) \, dz = -\frac{\pi i^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}  +2\sum_{m -n \text{ even}}^\infty \frac{i^{m-1} \epsilon^{m-n+1}}{m!(m-n+1)}
$$
The limit of this integral, unfortunately, is not well-defined as $\epsilon \to 0$;  all the terms in the sum with $m < n - 1$ will diverge, due to the factor of $\epsilon^{m-n+1}$.   (This is ultimately due to the fact that the function does not have a simple pole at $z = 0$, but rather a pole of order $n-1$.)

However, if one uses a nonstandard principal-value prescription that allows us to simply discard all the $\epsilon$-dependent terms, one does in fact obtain
$$
\mathrm{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^n} \, dx = - \Im \int_{III} f(z) \, dz = \frac{\pi (-1)^{(n-1)/2}}{(n-1)!}
$$
as desired.  I don't think that this is the usual way that it's done, but it's possible that the reference you are working from defines things in a non-standard way.  (It's also possible that I've made an error in my derivation, and I welcome corrections in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are looking at:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space\text{n}}:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

When $\text{n}$ is in the form of:

$$\text{n}=2\cdot\text{k}+1\tag2$$

Where $\text{k}\in\mathbb{N}$ (including $0$).

We know that $\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{2\cdot\text{k}+1}}$ is an even function, so we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space2\cdot\text{k}+1}=2\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{2\cdot\text{k}+1}}\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

Using the '[evaluating integrals over the positive real axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis)' property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space2\cdot\text{k}+1}=2\cdot\int_0^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{x^{2\cdot\text{k}+1}}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\space\text{d}\text{s}=$$
$$2\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+\text{s}^2}\cdot\frac{\text{s}^{2\cdot\text{k}}}{\Gamma\left(2\cdot\text{k}+1\right)}\space\text{d}\text{s}=\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(2\cdot\text{k}+1\right)}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{\text{s}^{2\cdot\text{k}}}{1+\text{s}^2}\space\text{d}\text{s}\tag4$$

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530926/finding-a-difficult-integral) answer we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_{\space2\cdot\text{k}+1}=\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(2\cdot\text{k}+1\right)}\cdot\frac{\pi\cdot\sec\left(\pi\cdot\text{k}\right)}{2}=\frac{\pi\cdot\sec\left(\pi\cdot\text{k}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2\cdot\text{k}+1\right)}\tag5$$