# How to compute this improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log z}{1+z^{\alpha}}dz $?

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Let $\alpha > 1$, how to compute this integral:

$$
I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log z}{1+z^{\alpha}}dz
$$

---

My try:

When $\alpha = 2$, I find that
$$
I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log z}{1+z^{2}}dz + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\log z}{1+z^{2}}dz = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log z}{1+z^{2}}dz + \int_{1}^{0} \frac{\log z}{1+z^{2}}dz = 0
$$
when I replace $z$ with $\frac{1}{t}$ of the integration. But I'm stuck when $\alpha \neq 2.$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The special function $P(s)=\int^\infty_0 \frac{\ln(x)dx}{1+x^s}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960336/the-special-function-ps-int-infty-0-frac-lnxdx1xs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compute

$$
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1}}{x^a+1} \, dx=\frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi  s}{a}\right)}{a}
$$

with Beta function.
Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\ln x}{x^a+1} \, dx&=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1}}{x^a+1} \, dx
\\&=-\frac{\pi ^2 }{a^2}\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{a}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{a}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: The same answer is given here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3960366