# Find integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{1+ x^3}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

The problem is apparently simple:
Find
$$\displaystyle{\int_0^\infty \!\!\frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x }$$

However, I have not been able to get around it. The usual "big circle" strategy is useless since we don't have parity. With substitution I was able to prove that, choosing $t = 1/x$, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \!\!\frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x =- \int_1^\infty \!\!\frac{t \log t}{1+ t^3} \,\mathrm{d} t
$$
And, analogously
$$
\int_1^\infty \!\!\frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x =- \int_0^1 \!\!\frac{t \log t}{1+ t^3} \,\mathrm{d} t
$$
However, this doesn't seem to be helpful. I could now write my integral as \begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \!\!\frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x= &
\int_0^1 \!\!\frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x + \int_1^\infty \!\! \frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x \\ 
= &\int_0^1 \!\!\frac{\log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x - \int_0^1 \!\!\frac{x \log x}{1+ x^3} \,\mathrm{d} x 
\\ 
= &\int_0^1 \!\!\frac{1-x}{1+ x^3} \log x \,\mathrm{d} x\\
\end{align}
This is a proper definite integral and I hoped it could be useful, e.g. to use integration by series But I couldn’t manage it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "big circle", but keyhole & sector contours both work. For the former, it's convenient if you first take $y=x^3$ so you only need to deal with one residue instead of three, but it's not strictly necessary. A generalization of the latter is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3960388). (Solutions also subdivide as to whether or not the logarithm factor is included by differentiating an arbitrary power of $x$ with respect to its exponent. There are even solutions with a $\log^2z$ factor in the integrand taken around the contour.)

Comment: Following the recommendation of @J.G., $I(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s}{1+x^n}dx$, making $\,x^n=t,\,\,I(s)=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty\frac{t{\frac{s+1}{n}-1}}{1+t}dt$, then $J_k=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^k x}{1+x^n}dx=\frac{d^k}{ds^k}I(s)\Big|_{s=0}$

Using the keyhole contour 
$$I(s)\big(1-e^{2\pi i(\frac{s+1}{n}-1)}\big)=\frac{2\pi i}{n}e^{\pi i(\frac{s+1}{n}-1)}$$
$$I(s)=\frac{\pi}{n}\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi}{n}(s+1)};\,\,J_k=\big(\frac{\pi}{n}\big)^{k+1}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\frac{1}{\sin x}\bigg|_{x=\frac{\pi}{n}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall use the residue theorem to compute. Consider the keyhole contour, [image]

and put $f(z)=\frac{\log^2(z)}{1+z^3}$. It is easy to estimate that the integral on the big circle and the small circle vanishes when $R\to\infty$ and $r\to 0$. Compute the residue at $z=e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}},e^{\pi i},e^{\frac{5 \pi i}{3}}$ and the sum of these residues is $\frac{4}{27} \left(1-3 i \sqrt{3}\right) \pi ^2$. According to the former discussion,
$$2\pi i\cdot \frac{4}{27} \left(1-3 i \sqrt{3}\right) \pi ^2=-4\pi i\int^\infty_0\frac{\log x}{1+x^3}\mathrm{d}x+4\pi^2\int^\infty_0\frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{1+x^3}.$$
Hence
$$ \int^\infty_0\frac{\log x}{1+x^3}\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{2 \pi ^2}{27}$$

Comment: Hi, I've never seen the keyhole contour method and I am having trouble with understanding it. Why do the $\gamma_\varepsilon$ and the $\gamma_{-\varepsilon}$ not cancel out?

Comment: @johncrimes That is because the angle of $z$ on $\gamma_{-\epsilon}$ is $2\pi i$, so the integral on $\gamma_{-\epsilon}$ is actually $\int (\log z+2\pi i)^2/(1+z^3)\mathrm{d}z$.

Comment: @johncrimes $\log$ is a multivalued function, so you need to fix a branch, in respect of which you compute.

Answer (score 2):

Recalling the evaluation of the Beta function [$\int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function), we see that for $0 < \alpha < \beta$ and $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \notin \mathbb{Z}$ we can evaluate the following integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha -1}}{1+x^{\beta}}\,\mathrm{d}x \overset{1-t = \frac{1}{1 + x^{\beta}}}{=} \frac{1}{\beta}\int_0^{1} t^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-1}(1-t)^{-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\beta}\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)= \frac{\pi}{\beta} \csc\left( \frac{\pi \alpha}{\beta}\right)
$$
where on the last step we used Euler's reflection formula [$\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)= \pi \csc(\pi z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General). Differentiating the above equation w.r.t. $\alpha$ on both sides gives
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)x^{\alpha -1}}{1+x^{\beta}}\,\mathrm{d}x = - \frac{\pi^2}{\beta^2} \csc\left( \frac{\pi \alpha}{\beta}\right) \cot\left( \frac{\pi \alpha}{\beta}\right) \tag{1}
$$
And substituting $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta =3$ gives your desired integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^{3}}\,\mathrm{d}x = - \frac{\pi^2}{9} \csc\left( \frac{\pi }{3}\right) \cot\left( \frac{\pi }{3}\right) = \boxed{- \frac{2\pi^2}{27}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}{d}x=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826136/686284) to integrate

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty&\frac{\ln x}{1+x^3}{d}x
= 
\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)\ln x}{1+x^3}{d}x \\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}
 - \underset{x^3\to x}{\frac{x^2\ln x}{1+x^3}}\ {dx}
= \frac89\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}{d}x
=-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want tou use residues, you have to play with the roots of unity.

Making the problem more general, compute the antiderivative
$$I=\int \frac{\log (x)}{1+x^n}\,dx=\int \frac{\log (x)}{\prod _{i=1}^n (x-r_i)}\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \int\frac{\log (x)}{x-r_i}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{\log (x)}{x-r_i}\,dx=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{r_i}\right)+\log (x) \log \left(1-\frac{x}{r_i}\right)$$

Recombine everything and use the bounds.

In fact, there is a nice formula for any $n>2$. Try to find it.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^3} dx$$
Let $x=e^t$, then
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t e^t dt}{1+e^{3t}}=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{t e^t dt}{1+e^{3t}}+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t e^t dt}{1+e^{3t}}=-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t e^{-t} dt}{1+e^{-3t}}+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t e^{-2t} dt}{1+e^{-3t}}$$
Using IGP expansion, we can write
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^n[-te^{-(3n+1)t}+te^{(3m+2)t} ] dt =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{(3n+2)^2}-\frac{1}{(3n+1)^2}\right)$$
Using $\psi^1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}$
$$\implies I=\frac{1}{36}\left([\psi^1(1/3)-\psi^{1}(5/6)]-[\psi^1(1/6)-\psi^1(2/3)]\right)$$
Using $\psi^1(z)+\psi^1(1-z)=-\pi^2\csc^2(\pi z)$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function , we get
$$I=\frac{1}{36}[\frac{4\pi^2}{3}-4\pi^2]=-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}.$$